# Отслеживание изменения в адресной строке хэш JavaScript или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, хеширование

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли отловить изменения в адресной строке хэш данных, всегда при вводе, стирании или вставке каких либо данных? Только без использовании HTML5, а только лишь в JavaScript или на jQuery. Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: имеется ввиду строка после `#`?

Comment: @Grundy
Да, после #

Comment: а почему _без использовании HTML5_ и что имеется под этим ввиду?

Comment: в HTML5 есть вроде плагин который с подобной задачей справляется. А мне хочется без использовании этих технологий попробовать, так сказать начать с базовых вещей этой технологии.

Comment: Что за плагин в HTML5?

Comment: На хабре как-то натыкался .. history название его, если память не изменяет

Comment: History API это немного другое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При изменении части URL следующей за `#`, включая сам знак `#` генерируется [событие hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e) {
  console.log(e.newURL);
});
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  location.hash = 'button_clicked';
});
```

```html
<a href="#first">first</a>
<button id="btn">Change Location hash in js</button>
```

Что характерно, данное событие является частью спецификации HTML5, но в предоставленной ссылке, также приведена реализация полифила.

Comment: Что-то у меня не получается отловить изменения в адресной строке((

Comment: пытаюсь отловить консолькой, но там пустота

Comment: @J.Doe, значит ты делаешь, что-то не так. При изменении адреса после `#` и применении его, срабатывает указанное событие. Если ты хотел отслеживать в реальном времени, то есть в сам момент редактирования добавляя или удаляя символ после # то естественно событие не срабатывает, так как hash еще не поменялся и все изменения могут быть отменены например с помощью клавиши Esc

Comment: В этом примере, работает отлавливание изменения, но тока при переходе по ссылке. А как без перехода по ссылке отлавливать изменения?

Comment: @J.Doe, при нажатии на кнопку тоже происходит изменение hash и так же отлавливается, предоставленный код абсолютно рабочий, и отлавливает любые изменения hash

Comment: Это так, только вот к примеру, я ввожу в адресную строку, условно: `site.ru/index.html#1` .. после не переходя дописываю к тому что есть ещё `2`, потом ещё `3` ... после я вставляю `ctrl+c` что-то ещё .. и т.д. не переходя `enter`ом, отлавливать не получается. Вот это, возможно при помощи какого нить события? Или JavaScript на это не способен?

Comment: @J.Doe, Нет такое не возможно в принципе - так как hash Не поменялся - событие и не происходит, и узнать об этом нельзя.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо что уделил мне время.